# configure subnet based on LLDP neighbour

Tags: networking, ansible

I am looking for some help to configure subnets between the routers

- please refer to the diagram1

Diagram:
[image: diagram]

Router Identification comes from the host variable file

eg.

```
ansible_host: 10.10.10.1
ID: 1
```

and

```
ansible_host: 10.10.10.2
ID: 2
```

I want to construct a subnet between the router 1 and 2 as follows
172.16.{12}.1/30 and 172.16.{12}.2/30, if the concatenating is difficult 10.{1}.{2}.1 and 10.{1}.{2}.2/30 is ok as well

I was following this great blog as a guideline

https://nwmichl.net/2020/07/05/fix-your-interface-description-with-ansible-and-cdp-lldp/

so the idea is

1. find the net-neighbour (from facts)

```
{
"net_neighbors": {
            "GigabitEthernet2": [
                {
                    "host": "CSR-2.example.com",
                    "port": "GigabitEthernet2"
                }
            ],
            "GigabitEthernet3": [
                {
                    "host": "CSR-2.example.com",
                    "port": "GigabitEthernet3"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

```
net_neighbors:
  GigabitEthernet2:
  - host: CSR-2.example.com
    port: GigabitEthernet2
  GigabitEthernet3:
  - host: CSR-2.example.com
    port: GigabitEthernet3
```

2, lookup neighbour's ID -> nebr_id (from hosts var)
3. contract ip as 10.{my_id}.{nebr_id}.x 255.255.255.252
4. if `my_id < nebr_id`, x=1 otherwise x=2 (lets assume there is no multipath)

If it helps, this is the code I use to configure loopbacks

```
- name: ip config for IOSXR
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli
  hosts: xr
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      ip_addr: "{{ '172.16.0.0/24' | ansible.utils.nthhost(ID) }}"
  - name: ip config for loopback (iosxr)
    cisco.iosxr.iosxr_config:
      lines:
      - description anchor interface
      - ip address {{ ip_addr }} 255.255.255.255
      parents: interface Loopback0
```

Hope this information is sufficient enough,

Sanjeewa